# How to assign a role with Discord.Net 1.0

Tags: c#, discord.net

So im trying to assign a role called "verified" when a user types "!verifyme".

This is what I have so far :

```
if (Context.Channel.Name == "role-assignment")
   {
        var user = Context.User;

        IRole role;

        await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);
    }
```

If anyone knows how to do this, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the snippet of code you are looking for:

```
var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "ROLENAME");
```